# Precise timing of very short image presentations in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, timing

I'm creating an online psychology experiment in JavaScript with the goal of studying people's ability to recognize images quickly (this RSVP, Rapid Serial Visual Presentation, paradigm is a common approach in psychophysics for isolating the feedforward, pre-attentive stages of visual processing). I aim to show a sequence of images for brief durations (e.g. 30 ms, 50 ms, 70 ms, etc.). For valid results, it's important to get the presentation times as precise as possible. Usually, this is done in a lab with specialized software or equipment, but this setup isn't an option for me. I recognize that some slop is an inevitable side effect of doing this experiment in a browser, but I'm hoping to (A) minimize it as much as possible, and (B) quantify, to the extent that I can, the amount of imprecision that actually occurred.

Right now, I'm preloading images, and am using `setTimeout()` to control stimulus duration. I'm assuming that experiment participants will use a variety of monitors (so refresh rates may differ) and browsers.

By eye, the timings of the images with my current approach seem to be wrong, and, in particular, highly variable. This is consistent with things I've read saying that variability for brief presentation times can be high.

Are there tools available to control timing more precisely in JavaScript? Additionally, are there tools that can measure/estimate the time an image was actually shown on screen? Finally, are there other options I should look at, e.g. compiling the sequence of images into a video, gif, etc.?

Comment: If you're relying on network bandwidth/latency/connectivity, there is no sure way to determine timing precisely. You can get a bit closer if you get everything local - local files, local server, etc, in which case you'll only have to worry about your local machine and its operating system (permitting you to be sure you're not running other applications, for example). Depending on your environment, maybe some sort of WAMP/XAMPP setup.

Comment: `requestAnimationFrame` might be faster than `setTimeout`, however you cannot control the timer yourself but only react to time.

Comment: A video might be a good idea indeed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setTimeout` does not specify when an action should take place. It only states that an action should take place once the timer has expired; but there's no way to guarantee when *exactly* the event will take place (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout).

When working on (psychological) expiriments, and when you have no control over the participant's environment, I would argue (apart from not entertaing such an uncontrolled environment in such cases) for claiming the whole tab the user is using (effectively blocking any interaction while the image is shown) or, as you already mention yourself, using an animated gif or sequence of images.

Or you can monitor and store the time the image was actually shown to your participant (using checking when the image comes into the `viewport`), and compare that timestamp with the participant's interaction. That would perhaps give the most valid results, as it will eliminate the inpredictability of `setTimeout`.